# Log in as the Administrator?

Tags: windows, administrator

A window that says "You must log in as the administrator to run this program" has appeared when attempting to run a piece of software.

How do I log in as the administrator so that this program can run sucessfully?

Answer (score 3):

Often this can happen because of User Account Control (UAC) in Windows 7, which drops rights by default. Right click the program you want to use and select "run as administrator", this should fix your issue.

If you actually want to *log in as* the administrator, you need to make the administrator account active first by running the following:

```
net user administrator /active:yes
```

Then you can log into it by the normal means.

Sometimes this means that you are a limited user, and you need administrative priveleges to do something. In this case, log in as a user that has administrative priveleges.

Answer (score 2):

There must be a reason why you're not an administrator. I would recommend contacting the administrator to help assist you with the program.

Answer (score 0):

Step one: Log off of your user account. You can do this by hitting the start button at the bottom left of the screen and hitting the log off button. If you cannot see the log off button, hit the arrow next to the shutdown button and hit log off.

Step two: Log in as the administrator by click on the administrator account. If you do not have the password to access the administrator account, contact the person who does.